# Convert JS object to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

If I defined an object in JS with:

```
var j={"name":"binchen"};
```

How can I convert the object to JSON? The output string should be:

```
'{"name":"binchen"}'
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` is the method you're looking for.

Comment: There's always that first time when you have to learn it.

Comment: JSON.stringify is also a good way to copy an object

Answer (score 2049, accepted):

All current browsers have native JSON support built in. So as long as you're not dealing with prehistoric browsers like IE6/7 you can do it just as easily as that:

```js
var j = {
  "name": "binchen"
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(j));
```

Comment: download [this script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in order for `JSON.stringify(j);` to work

Comment: Work on nodejs because node use same engine

Comment: This answer was posted a year before IE9 was released so at the time of writing IE8 was a modern browser indeed, or at least it was the newest IE available.

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't convert nested objects. Any solution for that..??

Comment: to be precise `j=JSON.stringify(j);` or `var newvar=JSON.stringify(j);`

Comment: If You need more readable json string You can use space parameter like `var formattedJSON = JSON.stringify(j, null, 2);`

Answer (score 123):

With `JSON.stringify()` found in [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or native in most modern browsers.

> ```text
> JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
>     value       any JavaScript value, usually an object or array.
>     replacer    an optional parameter that determines how object
>                 values are stringified for objects. It can be a
>                 function or an array of strings.
>     space       an optional parameter that specifies the indentation
>                 of nested structures. If it is omitted, the text will
>                 be packed without extra whitespace. If it is a number,
>                 it will specify the number of spaces to indent at each
>                 level. If it is a string (such as "\t" or "&nbsp;"),
>                 it contains the characters used to indent at each level.
> ```

Comment: For a bit more clarity: `replacer` _is_ optional, so if you want to still use the `space` arg you put `null` for `replacer`. If you are interested in using this function for pretty printing I found this answer to be also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/857209

Answer (score 36):

Check out updated/better way by Thomas Frank:

- [JSON stringify revisited](http://www.thomasfrank.se/json_stringify_revisited.html)

> Update May 17, 2008: Small sanitizer
>   added to the toObject-method. **Now
>   toObject() will not eval() the string
>   if it finds any malicious code in
>   it.For even more security: Don't set
>   the includeFunctions flag to true.**
>
> Douglas Crockford, father of the JSON concept, wrote one of the first stringifiers for JavaScript. Later Steve Yen at Trim Path wrote a nice improved version which I have used for some time. It's my changes to Steve's version that I'd like to share with you. Basically they stemmed from my wish to make the stringifier:
>
> - handle and restore cyclical references
> - include the JavaScript code for functions/methods (as an option)
> - exclude object members from Object.prototype if needed.

Answer (score 34):

You can use **JSON.stringify()** method to convert JSON object to String.

```
var j={"name":"binchen"};
JSON.stringify(j)
```

For reverse process, you can use **JSON.parse()** method to convert JSON String to JSON Object.

Comment: Thanks for adding the reverse process.

Answer (score 14):

`JSON.stringify(j, null, 4)` would give you beautified JSON in case you need beautification also

The second parameter is replacer. It can be used as Filter where you can filter out certain key values when stringifying. If set to null it will return all key value pairs

Answer (score 10):

In angularJS

```
angular.toJson(obj, pretty);
```

obj:
Input to be serialized into JSON.

pretty(optional):
If set to true, the JSON output will contain newlines and whitespace. If set to an integer, the JSON output will contain that many spaces per indentation.

(default: 2)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using AngularJS, the 'json' filter should do it:

```
<span>{{someObject | json}}</span>
```

Answer (score 9):

`JSON.stringify` turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

The conversion is an **Object to String**

`JSON.parse` turns a string of JSON text into a Javascript object.

The conversion is a **String to Object**

```
var j={"name":"binchen"};
```

to make it a JSON String following could be used.

```
JSON.stringify({"key":"value"});

JSON.stringify({"name":"binchen"});
```

For more info you can refer to this link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 7):

One custom defined for this , until we do strange from stringify method

```
var j={"name":"binchen","class":"awesome"};
var dq='"';
var json="{";
var last=Object.keys(j).length;
var count=0;
for(x in j)
{
json += dq+x+dq+":"+dq+j[x]+dq;
count++;
if(count<last)
   json +=",";
}
json+="}";
document.write(json);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"name":"binchen","class":"awesome"}
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/y78zum6v/

Comment: does not escape strings with quotation marks like: "a \" in a string"

Comment: That custom code is very incomplete. Does not support arrays, objects and special chars. Example: the json {"arr":["1", "2", "3"],"obj":{"a":"b"},"key\"with\\special}chars":"value"} will output {"arr":"1,2,3","obj":"[object Object]","key"with\special}chars":"value"} that is wrong!

Comment: ofcourse this code is just an example of playing with codes .. we should always use stringify ... JS had done the job already for us

Answer (score 7):

I was having issues with stringify running out of memory and other solutions didnt seem to work (at least I couldn't get them to work) which is when I stumbled on this thread. Thanks to [Rohit Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5052011/rohit-kumar) I just iterate through my very large JSON object to stop it from crashing

```
var j = MyObject;
var myObjectStringify = "{\"MyObject\":[";
var last = j.length
var count = 0;
for (x in j) {
    MyObjectStringify += JSON.stringify(j[x]);
    count++;
    if (count < last)
        MyObjectStringify += ",";
}
MyObjectStringify += "]}";
```

MyObjectStringify  would give you your string representaion (just as mentioned other times in this thread) except if you have a large object, this should also work - **just make sure you build it to fit your needs** - I needed it to have a name than array

Answer (score 5):

Woking... Easy to use

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var formData = $("form").serializeArray(); // Create array of object
  var jsonConvert = JSON.stringify(formData);  // Convert to json
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use native stringify function like this

```js
const j={ "name": "binchen" }

/** convert json to string */
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(j)

console.log(jsonString) // {"name":"binchen"}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get json properties value in string format use the following way

```
var i = {"x":1}

var j = JSON.stringify(i.x);

var k = JSON.stringify(i);

console.log(j);

"1"

console.log(k);

'{"x":1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

For debugging in Node JS you can use **util.inspect()**. It works better with circular references.

```
var util = require('util');
var j = {name: "binchen"};
console.log(util.inspect(j));
```

Answer (score 2):

The existing JSON replacements where too much for me, so I wrote my own function. This seems to work, but I might have missed several edge cases (that don't occur in my project). And will probably not work for any pre-existing objects, only for self-made data.

```js
function simpleJSONstringify (obj) {
    var prop, str, val,
        isArray = obj instanceof Array;

    if (typeof obj !== "object")
        return false;

    str = isArray ? "[" : "{";

    function quote (str) {
        if (typeof str !== "string")
            str = str.toString ();

        // When the actual variable was a number, it was returning a number between quotation marks
        // return str.match(/^\".*\"$/) ? str : '"' + str.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';

        // Now, we are verifing if is a number and, if it is, we remove the quotation marks
        str = str.match (/^\".*\"$/) ? str : '"' + str.replace (/"/g, '\\"') + '"';

        if (isNaN (str.replace (/^["]/, '').replace (/["]$/, '')))
            return str;
        else
            return str.replace (/^["]/, '').replace (/["]$/, '');
    }

    for (prop in obj) {
        if (!isArray) {
            // quote property
            str += quote (prop) + ": ";
        }

        // quote value
        val = obj [prop];
        str += typeof val === "object" ? simpleJSONstringify (val) : quote (val);
        str += ", ";
    }

    // Remove last colon, close bracket
    str = str.substr (0, str.length - 2) + ( isArray ? "]" : "}" );

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `JSON.stringify` to do such conversion - however remember that fields which have `undefined` value will not be included into json

```js
var j={"name":"binchen", "remember":undefined, "age": null };

var s=JSON.stringify(j);

console.log(s);
```

The field `remember` 'disappear' from output json

Comment: You just saved my day. I was not able to save  my object. the key that  fields which have undefined value will not be included into json solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use native function JSON.stringify()

```
let userJson = {
name : 'Richard'
}
let userJsonString = JSON.stringify(userJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
So in order to convert a js object to JSON String:
```

**The simple syntax for converting an object to a string is**

```
JSON.stringify(value)
```

**The full syntax is:**
    JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])

**Let’s see some simple examples. Note that the whole string gets 
 double quotes and all the data in the string gets escaped if 
needed.**

```
JSON.stringify("foo bar"); // ""foo bar""
JSON.stringify(["foo", "bar"]); // "["foo","bar"]"
JSON.stringify({}); // '{}'
JSON.stringify({'foo':true, 'baz':false}); /* " 
{"foo":true,"baz":false}" */



const obj = { "property1":"value1", "property2":"value2"};
const JSON_response = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(JSON_response);/*"{ "property1":"value1", 
"property2":"value2"}"*/
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify(param1, param2, param3);`

**What is: -**

param1 --> value to convert to JSON

param2 --> function to stringify in your own way. Alternatively, it serves as a white list for which objects need to be included in the final JSON.

param3 --> A Number data type which indicates number of whitespaces to add. Max allowed are 10.

Answer (score 0):

**convert str => obj**

const onePlusStr = '[{"brand":"oneplus"},{"model":"7T"}]';

const onePLusObj = JSON.parse(onePlusStr);

**convert obj => str**

const onePLusObjToStr = JSON.stringify(onePlusStr);

References of JSON parsing in JS: 

JSON.parse() : [click](http://w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

JSON.stringify() : [click](http://%20w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: References of JSON parsing in JS: JSON.parse() : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp   
JSON.stringify() : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Answer (score 0):

**The most popular way is below:**

```js
var obj = {name: "Martin", age: 30, country: "United States"};   
// Converting JS object to JSON string
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify() to do this

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162759/2227743).

Answer (score -2):

Very easy to use method, but don't use it in release (because of possible compatibility problems).

Great for testing on your side.

```
Object.prototype.toSource()

//Usage:
obj.toSource();
```