# How to simply output serialized form back as data in AJAX form in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Disclaimer: I am a total noob when it comes to ASP.NET.

I am using the following jQuery code to submit my form:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Foo/Save',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#dataInputForm').serialize(),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.success);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

My `Foo` controller code is this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

I know the AJAX post is working because I am seeing the alert with "success".  Next, I would like to see a var dump somehow of my serialized form.  I honestly do not know where to begin on the controller end but I would like my success alert to just dump my serialize form data just so that I can confirm that the form data that was submitted.

Essentially, this is what I would like the success alert to look like:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
```

BONUS: I would love to see an alternative way of submitting the data in JSON and seeing the success alert in JSON.

Comment: Have you considered using the jQuery Form plugin instead? Does a swell job of handling AJAXification of <form />s.

Comment: @kid0m4n No I have not. Thanks for the recommendation. At first glance, it is pretty sweet and helps streamline the client end of stuff. My main issue is with the server stuff. I'm a PHP guy struggling with ASP.NET =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly, .serialize() does not produce json, so the specified contentType is wrong.  you can drop the contentType option and $.ajax() will use the default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

next, on the controller, you need to bind the posted data to some object.  if you don't have an object defined that models your form data, you can use a FormCollection to build your result:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection collection)
{
    var result = new {Foo1 = collection["Foo1"], Foo2 = collection["Foo2"]};

    return Json(result);
}
```

in your success handler, you can then display the properties:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.Foo1);
    alert(data.Foo2);
}
```

or convert the object to a json string using [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) utility like so:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

for further reference:

[convert json object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-json-object-to-string)

Comment: Thanks ok. I have removed the contentType option and used the controller and the alert now says "undefined". I guess it is now expecting a JSON object instead of the serialized string?

Comment: what are you alerting?  data.success will be undefined since we're sending back a different object now.  did you try alert(data)?

Comment: yes, you're right. stupid mistake. I can now see a comma delimited list of of all my input names but no values. Is this what I should expect from this output? (I do values in my text boxes)

Comment: edited my answer to show you how to get values from the FormCollection, assuming your form has fields named Foo1 and Foo2

Comment: Ok...I have edited the field names to "Foo1" and "Foo2" and the alert that I see is `[object Object]`.

Comment: right, because you now have a javascript object.  see my edit for reading the object properties or converting the object to json

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the method signature of the method so that it is of time Stream.  Then you'll have to parse through the stream as a string and split the arguments by & (ampersands) where you'll have different KVPs.

```
public Stream samplePost(Stream stream)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string stringStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Dispose();
        NameValueCollection kvp = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stringStream);
        var number1 = Convert.ToInt32(kvp["number1"]);
        var number2 = Convert.ToInt32(kvp["number2"]);
        var sum = number1 + number2;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SUM IS " + sum.ToString());
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return s;
    }
```

That's a sample for taking in two numbers and returning them as a sum.  I think this should set you on your way.

Comment: Wow...this is a lot more complex than I expected. In PHP, this is 1-liner =)

Comment: I'm getting errors left and right on this code. For example: `The name 'WebOperationContext' does not exist in this current context`.  I did add the `using System.IO` though to allow use of `Stream`.

Comment: The example is for a WCF service, so it might not exist - try to remove that line and see what the default response type is for you.