# How to convert JSON to string?

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

I have a JSON object in JS, and I would like to convert it to string. Is it a function for this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you have JSON, it already is a string.

Comment: no, it is an object, like this: `{"foo":"bar"}`

Comment: Then it's not JSON, it's an object.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> Convert a value to JSON, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Answer (score 37):

You can use the [JSON `stringify` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
JSON.stringify({x: 5, y: 6}); // '{"x":5,"y":6}' or '{"y":6,"x":5}'
```

There is pretty good support for this across the board when it comes to browsers, as shown on http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON. You will note, however, that versions of IE earlier than 8 do not support this functionality natively.

If you wish to cater to those users as well you will need a shim. Douglas Crockford has provided his own [JSON Parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) on github.

Comment: +1 for showing that there are different possible results.

Comment: @amnotiam Objects, unlike arrays, have no particular order of properties. Good eye ;)

Answer (score 9):

Try to Use `JSON.stringify`

Regards