# How to parse JSON into a normal string?

Tags: json

Below is the JSON content. How can i parse it to a normal string or a table?

```
{   
    "dbDetails":"{\"dbName\":\"Test\",\"dbStatus\":\"UP\"}",
    "json":"success"
}
```

Comment: are you using any programming language?

Comment: using which language?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()`

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269469/how-to-convert-json-to-string

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Answer (score -1):

This may help and have a look at this

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: user007007, because it's a link-only answer. See the [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, specifically the "Provide context for links" section.