# Valid JSON file format in js

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to control whether given data is in JSON format.
For this control, I use `JSON.parse` with try catch. As;

```
var str= {
  "employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
  ]
}
try {
  parsed = JSON.parse(str);
} catch (err) {
    return "It is not valid JSON file";
}
```

But I want to stretch the rules.
I want to accept the following file format where fields does not have to be written inside "" as;

```
{
 employees:[
  {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"},
  {firstName:"Anna", lastName:"Smith"},
  {firstName:"Peter", lastName:"Jones"}
 ]
}
```

How can I do this? `JSON.parse` does not accept this format.

Comment: You could use `eval()` but you have to consider the security implications of this approach.

Comment: `{"name": "alex" , "age": "33"}` - this is not a json, it is a javascript object. Json is a string - `"{"name": "alex" , "age": "33"}"`

Comment: In your case str is already an object you don't need to parse it.

Comment: JSON.parse doesn't accept that format because it isn't valid. Keys _must_ be in quotes

Comment: Yes. But I want to make file format where keys are not in quotes acceptable. @ammoQ how can I use eval()?

Comment: Simply by writing `parsed = eval("("+str+")");` instead of `parsed = JSON.parse(str);`.

Comment: Using eval is not good practice. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea before using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269469/how-to-convert-json-to-string

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning your string and adding `"` manually.

```js
var str = '{name: "alex" , age: "33"}';
var d= '{employees:[{firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"},{firstName:"Anna",lastName:"Smith"},{firstName:"Peter",lastName:"Jones"}]}';

function processObject(str){
  var spaceReg = /\s/g;
  var _str = str.replace(spaceReg, "");
  
  var quoteReg = /\"/g;
  _str = _str.replace(quoteReg, "");
  
  var startBrace = /{/g;
  _str = _str.replace(startBrace,"{\"");
  
  var endBrace = /}/g;
  _str = _str.replace(endBrace,"\"}");
  
  var colon = /:/g
  _str = _str.replace(colon,"\":\"");
  
  var comma = /,/g
  _str = _str.replace(comma,"\",\"");
  
  var endBraceStr = /}\"/g
  _str = _str.replace(endBraceStr,"}");
  
  var startBraceStr = /\"{/g
  _str = _str.replace(startBraceStr,"{");
  
  var endBraceArrStr = /\]\"/g
  _str = _str.replace(endBraceArrStr,"]");
  
  var startBraceArrStr = /\"\[/g
  _str = _str.replace(startBraceArrStr,"[");
  
  console.log(_str)
  
  return JSON.parse(_str);
}

console.log(processObject(str))
console.log(processObject(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse has to be applied to a JSON string, not to a JSON object.