# How to convert json to string in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

In Ballerina I have a JSON object like this

```
json players = {
  "123": {"x":500, "y":400},
  "345": {"x": 300, "y":200}
}
```

I would like get an string from this object like:

```
string text = check <string>players;
```

This gives a runtime error:

```
'json' cannot be cast to 'string'
```

I am trying to get string representation of the JSON object and that is the reason I tried to cast it as above. 
What is the most suitable method to get a string representation of a JSON object in Ballerina?

Comment: This questions already has answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269469/how-to-convert-json-to-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This is ballerina not javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done as follows:

```
string text = players.toString();
```

I wasn't aware that this function existed.

Answer (score 4):

Adding more to [Riyafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599535/riyafa-abdul-hameed)'s answer, `string str = check <string> someJson;` will get the string value from a string-typed json. It will fail (with a runtime error) if the actual value of the json is something other than string (eg: number, boolean, json-array, json-object, etc).

So to get the string representation, despite the content of the json, `someJson.toString()` method should be used.