# DOM event to java via JSON

Tags: java, javascript, json, events, dom

Hey I'm trying to send a DOM Event (a mouse click captured on a FF extension) to a java webservice. It would be really useful if I could just use json and a bit of magic to jsonify the event and then maybe some java API to receive it =)

Do any of you know of anything that might do the trick?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You question consists of 2:

1) How to convert java script object to JSON?

Here is the answer: [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

2) How to send Json object to server?
The answer is: use AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have this mechanism already in place, I was just looking for something to actually convert the event object to json rather than having me to define the json structure for it and then from json to a java object.