# How to create the following type of json array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How to create the following type of json array using javascript?

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a JavaScript array, since the values are in single quotes. There are [a couple](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) of [introductions about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) out there, and how to convert a JavaScript data type to JSON is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string.

Comment: That already is a JSON array in JavaScript.

Comment: @mustafa.0x: No, it isn't. It's a *JavaScript* array in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that if you have almost any js object, even including quite complex functions/closures, you can use JSON.stringify().  It's worth looking through Crockford's well documented source for stringify():  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's both: http://www.json.org/ (look at the second item).

Comment: @mustafa.0x: No. What is posted is not valid JSON, since the keys and values are not in double quotes and there is no top level element. However even though it is a bit quirky, it is valid JavaScript. JSON is a data-exchange format like XML and can only exist within JavaScript in a string. The syntax of arrays and objects in JSON look similar to array and object literals in JS (in fact they are a subset), but that does not make JS arrays and object literals JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling: You are correct. However, I wasn't specific enough, this is a valid representation of JSON within JavaScript (i.e. if you parsed a JSON object, you could result in the above code, excluding the single-quotes).

Comment: @mustafa.0x: No, it isn't. Did you even read what Felix wrote? JSON is a *textual notation for data interchange*. If you have something in JavaScript code that isn't wrapped inside a quoted string, **by definition** it's not JSON. It's a JavaScript initializer. People constantly calling things JSON that aren't is very confusing for beginners and leads to a lot of questions on SO.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I did, but apparently no one is reading what I wrote. Is `'["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]'` a valid JSON array? Very well. If we `JSON.parse` that, will we get the array the OP provided? Yes. That is my entire point — the array provided is a valid representation of a JSON array within JavaScript (i.e. it could a pre-parsed JSON array). If you disagree then I have nothing else to say, as we'll then be arguing semantics.

Comment: @mustafa.0x: What you've posted in your comment just now is indeed a valid JSON array string. And **not** what's in the question, which you said was JSON, which isn't. I'm done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you have two options:

1. Create the array and then stringify it:

   ```
   var categories = [
               'Jan',
               'Feb',
               'Mar',
               'Apr',
               'May',
               'Jun',
               'Jul',
               'Aug',
               'Sep',
               'Oct',
               'Nov',
               'Dec'
           ];
   var json = JSON.stringify(categories);
   ```

   `JSON.stringify` exists on most modern browsers, and you can shim it. (There are several shims available, not least from [Crockford's github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) -- Crockford being the person who defined JSON.)
2. Or just create the JSON string directly:

   ```
   var json = '["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]';
   ```

---

Re your edit: That's not "an array" anymore, it's an object with an array in it (or an object with an object in it with an array in *that*). It doesn't fundmentally change the answer, though:

```
var xAxis = { categories: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ] };
var json = JSON.stringify(xAxis);
```

or

```
var json = '{"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]}';
```

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the `xAxis` layer in there. If so, it's just another layer around the above, e.g.:

```
var obj = { xAxis: { categories: [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ] } };
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

or

```
var json = '{"xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]}}';
```

More about JSON on [the JSON home page](http://json.org). Fundamentally, all strings must be in double (not single) quotes, and all property names must be in double quotes.