# Why does String([1,2])=="1,2" and not "[1,2]"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

What I want to do is change an array, say,

```
[1,2,[3,4],17.5]
```

into a sting like

```
"[1,2,[3,4],17.5]"
```

but not like

```
"1,2,3,4,17.5"
```

i.e. keeping all of the brackets. I tried using the built in String() function, but that gave me "1,2,3,4,17.5" Is there a built-in function or a code snippet that I can use to get "[1,2,[3,4],17.5]"?
Thanks!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha This is not a duplicate because this covers all arrays including things like ["meow",7,['Q',19.36]]

Comment: It *is* a duplicate because the answer thre applies to your question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: No, that is not what a duplicate _question_ means. However, even the questions are similar enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It doesn't matter what the duplicate question **means**. It matters whether or not the answer to **this** question is found in **the linked question**, which applies. The meaning of "duplicate" was changed. It's also the reason why you can't close against a duplicate with no upvoted answers.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Sorry but that is simply incorrect. When we mark question A as a duplicate of question B, that shall be because question A is the same as question B. Not because one or more answers on question A happens to fit question B also. The meaning of "duplicate" has not changed. We can no long close against a dup with no upvoted answers because SE recognised that marking question A as a duplicate of question B is a waste of time if doing so won't lead the OP of question A to their answer (though [this move was _widely_ condemned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928/155739)).

Comment: Nah, it's a dupe pretty much.

Comment: @Jimbo: I didn't say it's not a dupe. I actually said that the questions are similar enough. I have voted to close as a dupe. I'm just saying that it's the _questions_ that matter, not the _answers_. It's called "[this question is a] duplicate of [that question]", not "[this question is not a] duplicate of [that question, but some of the answers may happen to match up!]"

Comment: Why does it matter? We've, as a community, closed this as a dupe together. This discussion is over now.

Comment: @rightfold: Well, that escalated quickly! You're welcome to discuss the finer things of this in the [PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: And you are always welcome in the [C++ Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)!

Comment: Final thought: it might be a good idea to mention on the duplicated question that it also applies to arrays and strings (i.e. ""Meow"")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a JSON string:

```
array = [1,2,[3,4],17.5];
JSON.stringify( array );
```

See this question:

[Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Does not work on IE 7 and lower!

Comment: Just add json2 for IE7 and below support https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed! I missed that other question because I wasn't searching for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about conflicts with other pieces of code, you could change `Array.prototype.toString`

```
(function () {
    var arrayString = Array.prototype.toString;
    Array.prototype.toString = function toString() {
        return '[' + arrayString.call(this) + ']';
    }
}());

[1,2,[3,4],17.5].toString();
// "[1,2,[3,4],17.5]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could create a simple  method to do this if you don't want to use json  ,
Something along the following  :

```
(function toBracketedString(arr) {
     if (!_.isArray(arr)) { return ""; }
     var base = "[";

     for (var element in arr){
         base.append(","+element.toString());
     }
     base.append("]");
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I'm aware this is crappy code   I just wanted to get the idea across to you

Comment: I don't think this is a good example.. Someone asking a question like this, isn't helped with this sort of code..

Comment: edited to a better coding ,@Tim

Comment: I didn't even look at the first version, but any snippet that contains syntax errors is a bad example already. Not to mention all the other mistakes this code has (e.g. what's the point of calling `isArray()` on `arr` if it's not an array?)

Comment: @IngoBürk   there syntax errors fixed (I did it on the fly ). I'm trying to  get the idea across not   do the guys coding for him

Comment: @Pablo208 This would be a good alternative if it worked (I'm getting an Unexpected Identifier in V8), but on a side note, it will not work for nested arrays like ["meow",7,['Q',19.36]]

Comment: @SamQuinn sorry used of instead of in (been using coffeescript primarily as of late) , I think  node may also have issues with isArray so that may be another factior