# is there any function to create a json object from an array in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have an array

```
var user=[];

user['name']="joy";
user['age']= "12";
```

is there any function in node.js .So that i can get  the json output like

```
  {"name":"joy","age":"12"}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460769/creating-a-json-array-in-node-js

Comment: If you want object just use object literal not array. `fruits = {}`;

Comment: Is it acceptable if either `var fruits = {};` or the resulting json be `[{"name":"joy"},{"age":"12"}]` ?

Comment: @Vishwanath, its a dynamically creating array

Comment: @MattJones.Instead of looping.is there any defined function for that ?

Comment: @user2829759. result should be like {"name":"joy","age":"12"}

Comment: @LintoPD If you, as Vishwanath suggested, use `var fruits={};` instead of `var fruits=[];` then your problem should be solved

Comment: Fruits? And age under 21? Could you rename your variables to something else.

Comment: @user2829759.If i want to dynamically add one more item in to  the array . then  how can i do that

Comment: what do you want to do with the object generated?

Comment: @Vishwanath.I need to pass this json object to client side as a function result

Comment: @LintoPD As you would do with array `var obj = {}; obj["foo"] = "bar";` would give `obj = { foo: 'bar' } `

Comment: @user2829759.Thanks.I also posted one answer

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no predefined function in nodejs that will do it for you.
But as said by the others, you can do it manually or avoid the problem by defining the array as an objet.

Comment: ok. 
if i defined it as object.And i need to add one more item (sex =>male)dynamically.then how can i do it.can you mention a example

Comment: @LintoPD You shoud read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Just as you added the name and the age.
Objects can be used as array in this way (I am going to get yelled at for saying that).
For the example, it would be something like
`var user=[];

user['name']="joy";
user['age']= "12";
/* later in the code */
user['sexe'] = "male";`

Comment: @skornous I yell at you for saying that :P

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion.And i got the answer that i want.

```
var user = {};
user.name = "joy";
user.age =  "12";

JSON.stringify(user)
```