# Create JSON string for AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

There's something about this that makes me feel slightly dirty, what's the appropriate way to pass values to the data field?

Currently I'm doing this: **var jsonstring = "{ id: " + id + "}";**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CompleteCB(id) {
                var jsonstring = "{ id: " + id + "}";
               
                $.ajax({
                    
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/internal/completeholters.aspx/CompleteCB",
                    data: jsonstring,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#row" + id).fadeTo("fast", 0.33);
                }
            });
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: check [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

leave it as an object and call JSON.stringify()

```
var obj = {};
obj.id = 22;

JSON.stringify(obj); // "{"id":22}" a JSON formated string
```

Comment: You do it in one line: `JSON.stringify({id: id});` - no need to explicitly create an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the JSON directly, like so:

```
var query = { id: id };
```

Then in ajax call:

```
data: query,
```