# How to show console.log() in an app using ionic view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm busy testing my app on a browser and on my device with `ionic view`. I want to know if there is a way to have a browser type console.log displayed on my device with a label or something text based?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, sure you can make a `<div>` in your app at the bottom for example and log all the errors in there. So, everything you usually use with `console.log()` you would now append to this `<div>`.

However, I strongly suggest against that since it seems totally unpractical. What I would do in your case is run the application on your actual device with `ionic run` with these two options (as explained in the [official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/)):

> With live reload enabled, an app's console logs can also be printed to
>   the terminal/command prompt by including the `--consolelogs` or `-c`
>   option. Additionally, the development server's request logs can be
>   printed out using `--serverlogs` or `-s` options.

Comment: I will give it a try the `--consolelogs` does it work on mac terminal as well? @Nikola

Comment: The downside to this is that you can't really view log outputs of API response callbacks in the terminal. It will just show up as `[object Object]`.

Comment: @user1852651 you can use for JSON.stringify() that here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/4162803/1783311