# How to assign JSON string to Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, json

What is the correct way to assign a JSON string to a variable?  I keep getting EOF errors.

```
var somejson = "{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "value2"
}";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7rwq5zm/1/

Comment: I guess you're looking for `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have not escaped properly. You make sure you do:

```
var somejson = "{ \"key1\": \"val1\",\"key2\": \"value2\"}";
```

The easier way would be to just convert an existing object to a string using `JSON.stringify()`. Would recommend this as much as possible as there is very little chance of making a typo error.

```
var obj = {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "value2"
};

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Your answer is  definitely valid, but probably easier to use `'` than escaping everything.

Comment: good to know. Out of curiosity, what environments? I've never run into it. I'd assume it would be instantiated as a string, and any later parse would have no knowledge of how that string was made.

Comment: @DylanWatt meant to click edit, clicked delete. Tired, lol. I've run into some issues in nodejs on another project I worked on using single quotes. That being said, that may no longer be an issue in the newer versions >0.10.x

Answer (score 9):

If you want the string, not the object (note the `'` instead of `"`)

```
var somejson =  '{ "key1": "val1", "key2": "value2" }';
```

If you want a string declared with multiple lines, not the object (newline is meaningful in Javascript)

```
var somejson =  '{'
 + '"key1": "val1",' 
 + '"key2": "value2"' 
 + '}';
```

If you want the object, not the string

```
var somejson =  { "key1": "val1", "key2": "value2" };
```

If you want a string generically

```
var somejson =  JSON.stringify(someobject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to assign JSON string value to a variable.

```
var somejson = JSON.parse('{"key1": "val1","key2": "value2"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JSON.stringify function. 
See the answers here - [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

```
var somejson = {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "value2"
};
somjson = JSON.stringify(somejson);
```