# javascript convert list value of array into json

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array object like this:

```
var a = {
    data: [
      'name': 'somename',
    ]

}
```

Here I want to check if my array has list. If it is then I want convert the list into json and return new value.

I can do this in python like:

```
assets = {}
            for k,v in data.items():
                if type(v) is list:
                    assets[k] = json.dumps(v)
                else:
                    assets[k] = v
```

How can I achieve this in javascript ??

Comment: Ever used google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object is array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array)

Comment: @JohannesJander I dont want to convert all data to json.. can you look at python code ??

Answer (score 0):

There is not list type in javascript.

The type `Array` is the one closer to your question.

To check if a variable v is an Array you can do the following:

```
if (v instanceof Array) {
   // Do something if v is an array
}
```