# Convert a JavaScript object to an other format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript object to an other.

Let's say that my JavaScript input object looks like this :

```
$scope.name_person= [{
    "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
 }]
```

The output should be like this :

```
 $scope.name_perso=  [{ 

  "values":[
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
           ]
  }]
```

this is my code :

```js
function convert(arr) {
    return $.map(unique(arr), function(name){
        return {
            values: $.grep(arr, function(item){
                return item.name == name
            })
        } 
    });
}

function unique(arr) {
    var result = [];
    $.map(arr, function(item){
        if ($.inArray(item.name, result))
            result.push(item.name);
    })
    return result;
}

$scope.data=convert($scope.name_person);
```

Any Adivice ?

Comment: whats wrong with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Should: `[{ 

  "values":[
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
           ]
  }]` be: [{ 

  `"values":[{
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
           }]
  }]`?

Comment: ` "values":[
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
           ]` this is not even a valid javascript syntax

Comment: The output that you want doesn't appear to be valid syntax.  What do you really want?

Comment: i want to use this fuction in angulars Js, yeh the output should be like this: [{ "values":[{ "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith" }] }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.name_person= [{
    "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
 }];
   var array = [{'values':[]}];
  angular.forEach($scope.name_person,function(item,i){
         array[0].values.push(item);
      });
  
  $scope.name_person = [];
  $scope.name_person = array;
  console.log(array);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

     <pre>{{name_person | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

try this

```
  var array = [{'values':[]}];
  angular.forEach($scope.name_person,function(item,i){
     array[0].values.push(item);
  });

  $scope.name_person = [];
  $scope.name_person = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.name_person=  [{ 

  "values":[
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
           ]
  }]
```

You are trying to create an associative array but, associative arrays are not supported in Javascript, for that you need to use objects(which are also special type of arrays with key:value pair).

What you can do is :

```
    var $scope = {};
    $scope.newObject = [];
    $scope.namePerson = [{
        "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
    }];
    $scope.newObject.push(
        {
            "values": $scope.namePerson[0]
        }
    );

    console.log($scope.newObject);
```

This will return

```
[{ 
   "values":{
       "firstName":"Jean","lastName":"Smith"
       }
}]
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but i get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . And my name Person doesn't contains one element :o