# Convert a object in javascript to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a jsonStrng like `var sourceJsonStr= {"foo":25,"xyz":49};` I want similar in `JSON` object like `var targetStrJson = [['foo', 25], ['xyz', 49]]`. How do convert sourcejson to targetjson in javascript.

Comment: you have an object, and you want a nested array ... there is no JSON involved in the question or any potential answer

Comment: Go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var source = {"foo": 25, "xyz": 49};
var target = Object.keys(source).map(key => [key, source[key]]);

console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this.

```js
var sourceJsonStr= {"foo":25,"xyz":49}; 
var targetStrJson = [];
for(var key in sourceJsonStr){
   targetStrJson.push([key, sourceJsonStr[key]]);
}

console.log(targetStrJson);
```

Using `.map` in `es5`

```js
var sourceJsonStr = {
  "foo": 25,
  "xyz": 49
};
var targetStrJson = Object.keys(sourceJsonStr).map(function(key){
  return [key, sourceJsonStr[key]];
});

console.log(targetStrJson);
```