# OData returns array instead of JSON - How to convert?

Tags: javascript, json, odata

I've been trying to figure how to properly receive an OData response in Javascript for a couple of days. The problem is the response is formatted as an array instead of JSON, so the function `JSON.parse(mydata)` does not work with the data I am receiving.

My question is two-fold: What is the proper way to request OData to send a response as JSON and/or how do I format my current response to be JSON?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: requestUri,
                dataType: "script",
                accept: "application/json",
                success: function(data, request) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }})
```

Here is an example response of logging the variable `data` with `console.log`:

`{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#Movies","value":[{"Title":"Pulp Fiction","Genre":"Action","RunTime":0,"Sales":0,"Key":2}]}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: @Brian I was really wondering more if my OData request was incorrect and that question has nothing to do with OData.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add it to a variable and access it just like that.

```
var v={"@odata.context":"http://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#Movies","value":[{"Title":"Pulp Fiction","Genre":"Action","RunTime":0,"Sales":0,"Key":2}]};
//v.value[0] is a json object
console.log(v.value[0]);
```

or skip the assignment altogether and access this way:

```
data.value[0]
data.value[0].Genre
data.value[0].RunTime
etc....
```

Comment: Thanks, that second example is exactly what I was looking for. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is the response is formatted as an array instead of JSON

It can't be. You can't send "an array" over HTTP. You have to encode it somehow … e.g. as JSON.

jQuery will, unless you override it with the `dataType` option, use the `Content-Type` HTTP response header to determine how the data is encoded. If it is JSON, it will parse the JSON.

The value of `data` is what you would get if you read the raw `responseText` and passed it through `JSON.parse`.

So just don't try to parse it manually. jQuery has done it for you.

Skip the step:

> ```
> var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
> ```

… and just work with `data`.

NB: The output of `JSON.parse` is an object, array or other JavaScript data type. JSON data is what you get from `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Worth to mention that the expected data lies in `data.data`

Comment: I had no idea that changing the dataType overrides. That helped immensely, thanks!

Comment: @baao do you mean `data.value`?

Answer (score 0):

If the response is in OData format, as your example shows, but you want it in JSON format that can be parsed by *JSON.parse*, add **$format=json** to the OData query, so long as the OData endpoint supports it. I know Dynamics 365 does not.