# How do you make JS think that a string is JSON?

Tags: angularjs

how to convert in json object?
I also tried the following.

```
 $scope.getEval = function (str) {
                return eval(str);
 };
        try {
            s = $scope.getEval("\nexports = { emptyFunction: function () {  \n      exit();    },    getUserName: function () {        if (!variable.global_name) {            exit(changeFlowAndStep('get_user_name', 0, {global_first_time_done: false}, true));        } else {            exit({variable:{global_first_time_done: true}});        }    }}")

            for (var i in s) {
                s[i] = s[i].toString();
            }
            $scope.s = s;
            console.log($scope.s)


        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Comment: Is `exports = { emptyFunction: function () ...` the string you want to convert from json to object?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a javascript object, it is easy to generate a JSON string with `JSON.stringify()` and if you have a JSON string, it is easy to generate a javascript object with `JSON.parse()`

```js
// going from JSON to JS object...

var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.count);


// from JS object to JSON string...

var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str);
```

from:

- [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)
- [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `eval` works, as you can see when you call `console.dir($scope.s);`

It is possible to use `json = JSON.stringify(obj);` and `obj = JSON.parse(json);`. However it appears JSON.stringify ignores object fields with a function as a value. That is your string is not a useful json string.