# Convert encoded application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data to json object

Tags: javascript

A client wants to be able to make xmlhttp ajax requests with the default content type of content-type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" but sending the data in the form the API expects application/json. So the request comes across as this:

```
  var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:80/api/metadata/taxonomy",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "62a245ad-a0a2-4dd3-bf84-37f622f00b7d"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\n\t\"practice\": [\"Learning\"]\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But the API expects to be able to get req.body as a JSON object it can immediately use:

```
"{"practice":["Learning"]}"
```

Can I transform this "{\n\t\"practice\": [\"Learning\"]\n}" to this "{"practice":["Learning"]}" in some safe/suggested manner? (without some home grown parsing function or regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `JSON.parse` function can be used for this:

```
try{JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data))}
```

will convert strange json with newlines to standard one line string json.

`JSON.parse`
Parses the json into an object

`JSON.stringify`
Turns an object into a one line formatted JSON object

`try`
JSON.parse will fail if an invalid json string is passed. (\ns are valid in json.parse)

If this you meant converting `"{\n\"your\":\n \"object\"}"` to a javascript object like `{"your": "object"}`, you can just use `try{JSON.parse(variablename)}`

According to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string?rq=1%20), for older browsers you may need [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Answer (score -1):

You can actually post JSON as body.

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:80/api/metadata/taxonomy",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "62a245ad-a0a2-4dd3-bf84-37f622f00b7d"
  },
  "dataType" : "json"
  "processData": false,
  "data": { "practice": ["Learning"] }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Notice that theirs a new property which tells that data type to be posted is **JSON** and and now in `data` property the value is in JSON format instead of string.

Hope this solves your problem.