# How to convert the given data into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want convert the following data into JSON object.
But when is used JSON.parse() command it returns:

```
var r = JSON.parse(t)
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Here is sample data string which is to be converted

```
 var t = { message: 
       [ { timestamp: 1522007930599,
           tags: [Array],
           _id: '5aacb7cc0281b558debacf26',
           message_link: 'String',
           __v: 0 },
       ] }
```

Comment: I should add that there is no such thing as JSON object, JSON stands for `JavaScript Object Notation`. i.e. a format to represent javascript objects as string.

Comment: Before you put the issue you must be search about it. Look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string?rq=1 and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: As `t` is already a `JSON Object` . Why again `JSON.parse(t)` ?

Comment: @RohitJindal — `t` is a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. Using `JSON.parse` is wrong, but not for the reason you suggest.

Comment: Ya i am sorry,my bad for not researching beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) converts **from** JSON to a JavaScript data structure.

To go the other way you need [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: so how do i use it to convert to JSON

Comment: @VinayakShrivastava — The same way you are attempting to use `JSON.parse`