# How to store the JSON value fetch from a URL using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new to JQuery. I am trying to develop a small travel website for checking PNR. I am currently using an API provided by one of the travel company. As soon as we hit the API Url, browser displays the result in JSON format.

I am using JQuery, JS and HTML. I want to know how to store the JSON value (in string format) retrieved from hitting an API, in a variable and use it later in the script.

PS: Though I have found many answer in Stackoverflow but none of the result works. Kindly help with the appropriate value.

Sample Code: (I am using one textbox and button)

```
    <script>
function search_pnr(){
var pnr = $('#input_pnr').val();
var result;
var url = "http://api website/pnr"+pnr;

//Suggest the code here, to fetch the result from url and store in the variable result.

</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter PNR" id ="input_pnr"/>
<input type="button" value="Search PNR" onclick="search_pnr()"/>
```

Below is the JSON value getting from server

```
{"to_station": {"lng": 77.2888291, "name": "ANAND VIHAR TERMINAL", "lat": 28.6118176, "code": "ANVT"}, "total_passengers": 1, "pnr": "6717552286", "journey_class": {"name": null, "code": "3A"}, "train": {"classes": [{"available": "N", "name": "SECOND AC", "code": "2A"}, {"available": "Y", "name": "THIRD AC", "code": "3A"}, {"available": "N", "name": "SECOND SEATING", "code": "2S"}, {"available": "N", "name": "FIRST AC", "code": "1A"}, {"available": "Y", "name": "AC CHAIR CAR", "code": "CC"}, {"available": "N", "name": "FIRST CLASS", "code": "FC"}, {"available": "N", "name": "3rd AC ECONOMY", "code": "3E"}, {"available": "N", "name": "SLEEPER CLASS", "code": "SL"}], "days": [{"code": "MON", "runs": "N"}, {"code": "TUE", "runs": "Y"}, {"code": "WED", "runs": "N"}, {"code": "THU", "runs": "Y"}, {"code": "FRI", "runs": "N"}, {"code": "SAT", "runs": "Y"}, {"code": "SUN", "runs": "N"}], "number": "22405", "name": "BGP-ANVT GARIB RATH"}, "from_station": {"lng": 86.9828131, "name": "BHAGALPUR", "lat": 25.2494829, "code": "BGP"}, "passengers": [{"booking_status": "CNF/G12/36/GN", "no": 1, "current_status": "CNF/-/0/GN"}], "reservation_upto": {"lng": 77.2888291, "name": "ANAND VIHAR TERMINAL", "lat": 28.6118176, "code": "ANVT"}, "response_code": 200, "boarding_point": {"lng": 86.9828131, "name": "BHAGALPUR", "lat": 25.2494829, "code": "BGP"}, "debit": 3, "doj": "25-08-2018", "chart_prepared": false}
```

Kindly also help how to read both the objects and array in the given JSON.

Comment: Do some research into using ajax. This question is really far to broad based on guidelines in the [help]. You shouldn't have any problem finding lots of ajax tutorials to get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to fetch the result from the url

```
var result;
var url = "http://api website/pnr"+pnr;
$.ajax
({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        result = data;
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to show the var result in an alert box?

Comment: @MdKamranAzam, Edited the answer.

Comment: Tried.. but its showing [object Object]. I want to show the complete JSON in alert box.

Comment: @MdKamranAzam your original question was about fetching the result, right? But you marked some other answer as accepted.

Comment: I saw your edited code after the one I saw using stringify.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse JSON and how to read each object. This should give you good start

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api_website/pnr"+pnr,
    data: data,
    success: function(resultData) { 
        console.log(resultData);

        var to_station = resultData.to_station;
        var trains = resultData.train;
        var passengers = resultData.passengers;

        alert("Station Name: "to_station.name);
        alert("Passengers: "passengers.booking_status);


    },
    error(function() { 
        alert("Something went wrong"); 
    }
});
```

You can read more bout [how to read JSON here](https://mytwocents.tech/read-json-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: url
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
    // see what properties you need from data object and save it to variable
    var data = data
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing,

Use a javascript file....API calls are better off done in a js file rather than in a script tag.
Second thing, if you want to store it in a json format,
you can store it in a value like the way you have declared your url variable.
Since, you are fetching the data, I'm assuming this is a get request, you can find more information about them in the following links -

1. https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/
2. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Also, if the data isn't very sensitive, you can store it in the local storage of your browser, so that you can access it later on in other web pages as well.

In your current json data, I would say that if you declare it to a variable say
`apiResult`
Your to_station would be `apiResult.to_station`, the lng value would be `apiResult.to_station.lng` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Hope any of this helps, and good luck.

Everyone already added the AJAX examples, so I will leave that out.

So for reading the objects, you just have to parse what you need through various means, if you know what the object looks like and exactly what you need you can use dot notation. If you are looking to grab things more dynamically you can using higher order functions or for loops as well as Object prototypes example getting the entries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

You might consider using localStorage for storing the information depending on what you are using it for which is a built-in Web API
here is MDN's definition

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage
>   object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across
>   browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except
>   that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends —
>   that is, when the page is closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use AJAX. You have to be sure how the server will retrieve the data. If it is in a JSON format do:

```
<script>
    function search_pnr(){
        var pnr = $('#input_pnr').val();
        var result;
        var url = "http://api website/pnr"+pnr;
        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
            result = data;
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                // whatever with keys and values if needed
            }
        );

    }
</script>
```

[Ref w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp)

[JQuery official website](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score -1):

All current browsers have native JSON support built in. So as long as you're not dealing with prehistoric browsers like IE6/7 you can do it just as easily as that:

```
var j={"name":"binchen"};
JSON.stringify(j); // '{"name":"binchen"}'
```

For more info kindly visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Exactly, what I was searching for.Thanks