# Unable to save the app info returned from Google-Play-Scraper?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to crawl the app info based on app id (e.g. com.instagram.android) in Google Play.

I used the npm package as the crawler: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper

I don't have any javascript experience before, I don't know how to modify it for my purpose.
For now, I cannot use that for crawling a list of app IDs, and save the returned results as a *.txt for further analysis.

I have tried their sample code, and it runs well. But I could only see the returned results by `.then(console.log, console.log)`. How could I save the results to a .txt file???

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

I am stuck here, could anyone help me on this issue? I have tried many different ways to solve this problem, but they all didn't work... I am really confused about how to save the value returned to .txt file

I tried to save all the potential variables into the .txt files, only the info like:

```
[object]
[object promise]
```

are saved.

I tried to save it like this:

```
var first = gplay.app({appId: 'com.instagram.android'});
app_result = first.then((result) => console.log(result));

fs.writeFile('App_Result.txt', app_result, (err) =>{
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log('App_Result saved!');
    });
```

I understand that this may be caused by the strategy of Promise, which I need to wait for the Promise resolved and then the results could be returned. But I don't know how to figure out it since I am really new for the javascript.

Comment: How are you saving the values to the `.txt` files?

Comment: You need to convert the object to a string. `JSON.stringify(app_result)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson I tried to save different variables (e.g. console.log,  result, app_result),  I added one way I tried in the post. Please check it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson Yes. I have tried the JSON.stringfy(app_result),  it only save "{}" to the .txt file

Comment: You are stringifying a Promise that has not yet resolved. See my answer shortly.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson It seems like I need to wait for the Promise solved, but how Can I save it instead of only viewing in the console.

Comment: @jwilson  Thanks a lot.  Yes. It seems like that. I also checked the Promise definition things before, but since I am really new in the .js. I could not figure out a way to solve it.  I have been stuck here for a whole afternoon. T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: JavaScript by default prints objects very unhelpfully, something like `[Object object]` or similar. If you need more information, try replacing `console.log` with `data => JSON.stringify(data)`.

Second, due to the nature of Promises, you'll have to chain another `.then` onto your existing code. Something like

```
const gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream('App_Result.txt');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(result => JSON.stringify(result))
  .then(text => file.write(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `app_result` will not equal the result of the promise but rather the promise itself.

You also have to convert the object to a string using `JSON.stringify` before you can write it to a file.

Try writing an async function like this.

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    const app_result = await gplay.app({appId: 'com.instagram.android'});

    fs.writeFile('App_Result.txt', JSON.stringify(app_result))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Einar. I will learn to understand this function.