# How to extract a javascript object as json from a HTML page using python or nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js

https://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/yeastmine/customQuery.do

The above webpage has something like this. As far as I understand, JSON does not support single quote, only double quote is allowed. So the things in {} is not a valid JSON object. What is the best way to extract this object from the resulted HTML page and convert it to JSON? Thanks.

```
var helpMap = {'NcRNAGene': ...
```

This one mentions `JSON.stringify`. But I am not sure how to first get helpMap as JS object in the first place in python or nodejs.

[Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: What data do you want from that website exactly? It does look like they have an API you can interact with.. See [here](https://yeastmine.yeastgenome.org/yeastmine/api.do?subtab=python) and [here](https://github.com/intermine/intermine-ws-python-docs/) for more. It would appear they're using Intermine to serve their API.

Comment: But the things that I want extract here is about the metadata, not the data saved in intermine.

Comment: And what data do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: Just that list in helpMap.

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the same thing as you... Can you post a screenshot of what you want to gather?

Comment: I already figure the answer. See below.

Answer (score 1):

In the console of that website you can write javascript. In this case you are right that JSON.Stringify is what you want here, you use it by passing the javascript object `helpMap` into it as a parameter, the result is the JSON-encoded string:

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(helpMap)
console.log(jsonString)
```

You should be able to copy that json string out of your console (in chrome there will be a "Copy" button at the end of it).

Comment: No. I need it to be at the command line instead of in the browser, as I mentioned python or nodejs.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought you just wanted to get the JSON once, but it sounds like you want to reload the page to get changes. Probably you want to download/scrape the webpage https://blog.bitsrc.io/https-blog-bitsrc-io-how-to-perform-web-scraping-using-node-js-5a96203cb7cb then find the bit of javascript you're concerned with, either by searching for the line it's on looking for `var helpMap = ` or something like that, then parse that line as javascript https://www.npmjs.com/package/esprima, then convert that into JSON.

Comment: Once I called `esprima.parseScript("var helpMap = ...")`, how eval it to get the object of helpMap?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the webpage is downloaded to x.html, run the following.

```
grep '^ \+var helpMap' < x.html | ./main.js
```

`main.js` has the following code.

```
fs=require('fs');
data = fs.readFileSync(process.stdin.fd);
eval(data.toString());
console.log(helpMap);
```

Then use `JSON.stringify()` on `helpMap` if necesssary.