# How to Convert array of Json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

```
    var x=[{"name":"james","age":"23"},{"name":"job","age":"55"}];
```

How to convert array of json object to below response

```
   {{"name":"james","age":"23"},{"name":"job","age":"55"}};
```

Comment: the below is invalid.

Comment: The target format is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

```js
  let x=[{"name":"james","age":"23"},{"name":"job","age":"55"}];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

The desired output isnt proper JSON. To convert any javascript object into a json string simply use the function `JSON.stringify(obj)`. `JSON.parse(string)` can be used to create an object out of a string.