# Convert json object string to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have my responseJson like this

```
const responseJson = [
      {
        device_id: "arena-FnVq4HTwtBg6JqqBxWBB7W",
        timestamp: "2020-02-10T20:52:00.000Z",
        data: "{"type": "DATA", "unitID": "arena-FnVq4HTwtBg6JqqBxWBB7W",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "voltage": [130.0222, 129.9743, 129.9567, 129.9853, 130.0043, 130.0257, 130.067,
         130.1005, 130.0698, 130.1056],
         "frequency": [60.0005, 60.0001, 59.9984, 59.9999, 59.9992, 59.9971, 59.9977,
         59.9979, 59.999, 59.9985],
         "timestamp": 1581367920000,
         "phaseAngle": [2.5766, 2.5769, 2.5768, 2.5761, 2.5754, 2.574, 2.5718, 2.5706,
          2.569, 2.5677]}"
      }
    ]
```

my `data` is a string not an object. How can i parse my data to get this

```
const responseJson = [
      {
        device_id: "arena-FnVq4HTwtBg6JqqBxWBB7W",
        timestamp: "2020-02-10T20:52:00.000Z",
        data: {"type": "DATA", "unitID": "arena-FnVq4HTwtBg6JqqBxWBB7W",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "voltage": [130.0222, 129.9743, 129.9567, 129.9853, 130.0043, 130.0257, 130.067,
         130.1005, 130.0698, 130.1056],
         "frequency": [60.0005, 60.0001, 59.9984, 59.9999, 59.9992, 59.9971, 59.9977,
         59.9979, 59.999, 59.9985],
         "timestamp": 1581367920000,
         "phaseAngle": [2.5766, 2.5769, 2.5768, 2.5761, 2.5754, 2.574, 2.5718, 2.5706,
          2.569, 2.5677]}
      }
    ]
```

I have tried JSON.parse but no help
Here is what i get when i console.log
`console.log(responseJson.data)` throws `undefined`
`console.log(JSON.parse(responseJson.data))` throws `C:\Users\aravi\Desktop\React\Reactnative\BrixonApplication_App\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:94 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Looks like whatever is serving that JSON is encoding the data property and then again encoding the whole object.  Fix that server-side.

Comment: if your first snippet of code is really like that, then your `responseJson` is invalid and should throw and error, since  `data` value has a syntax error

Comment: You need to assign this `JSON.parse(responseJson[0].data)` to data. you need to loop if you have more than one object.

Comment: @calvin I don't think that's invalid until string itself is a valid json object or array.

Comment: ```console.log(responseJson.data)``` thows undefined and
```console.log(JSON.parse(responseJson.data))``` throws errors

Comment: Internal double quotes should be escaped or should be single quote to make it valid json

Comment: @CalvinNunes closed the question ?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: ok, voted to reopen. But lets go: `responseJson` is an array, not object, so it has no `data` property/key, you can access the first object by `responseJson[0]` as mentioned in some comment above, that's why you get undefined. Second error: you are trying to parse "undefined" with JSON.parse, that's why you get "Unexpected token u".

Comment: I have only one object and i tried either ways and now ```responseJson[0]``` this gives ```TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined```

Comment: are you absolutely sure that you don't have any other error before? I'll add a working snippet in your question, and you'll see that the code you posted have a syntax error that I mentioned in my first comment

Comment: ```console.log(JSON.parse(responseJson[0].data));``` this worked in parsing

Comment: jsonlint says the (new) string is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse('your string here')`, it will convert your string to an object