# Convert JS Object to Raw string

Tags: javascript, json, string

i want to convert js object to following format.

**I need backward slash before every dobule quotes.**

Input:

```
{key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}
```

Output:

```
'{key1: \"value1\", key2: \"value2\"}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Why do you want to produce invalid JSON?

Comment: for building graphql query @VLAZ

Comment: Don't you need JSON for that? Or objects? I'm not familiar with GraphQL but I thought it doesn't use random strings that are neither objects nor JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to do that, that would be the answer however:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(yourObject)) {
  console.log(`\\"${key}\\": \\"${value}\\"`);
}
```