# Convert json array of objects to string

Tags: python

I have this json file:`[ {"gy":"1","te":"ggjf" }, {"gy":"2","te":"hgfjm" } ]`

can you help me convert this json array of object to string?

Comment: For sure this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this data stored in a file named `file.json`, you can convert it into a string using:

```
import json

file = open('file.json')
data = json.load(file)
file.close()

string = json.dumps(data)
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

so I did not really get what is the desired output, a string or an array.

so if you have:

```py
>>> a = '[ {"gy":"1","te":"ggjf" }, {"gy":"2","te":"hgfjm" } ]'
```

if you want the array:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(a)
[{'gy': '1', 'te': 'ggjf'}, {'gy': '2', 'te': 'hgfjm'}]
```

if you want the string:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(a))
'[{"gy": "1", "te": "ggjf"}, {"gy": "2", "te": "hgfjm"}]'
```

if none of the above is your desired output, please clearify more :-)

official json docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json