# JS: How to convert string to JSON Format using replace and then JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, format

I am having trouble converting my string to JSON format.

I have this specific kind of string:

```
{Object1=Text Goes Right Here, and Here, Object2 = Another Text Here}
```

I wanted to convert it to something like this

```
{"Object1":"Text Goes Right Here, and Here", "Object2":"Another Text Here"}
```

Can anybody help me figure out how to properly convert this.

I tried using **replaceAll** but it keeps on breaking on the comma.

```
str.replaceAll('=', '":"').replaceAll(', ', '", "').replaceAll('{', '{"').replaceAll('}', '"}')
```

And it ended up like this.

```
{"Object1":"Text Goes Right Here", "and Here", "Object2":"Another Text Here"}
```

I also tried regexm but it is not replacing the actual strings.

```
/[^[a-zA-Z]+, [a-zA-Z]+":$']/g
```

A regex or anything that could help would be fine. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS object to JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string)

Comment: is that really what your initial string looks like? That's not valid anything. Can you show what it actually looks like?

Comment: @Kinglish yes, that was the actual string I am getting from the result. I find it weird but I need to find a workaround just to format my object in proper JSON format.

Comment: can we depend on the equal sign only happening with the assignments (Object1 = ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Positive Lookahead**

https://regex101.com/r/iCPrsp/2

```js
const str = '{Object1=Text Goes Right Here, and Here, Object2 = Another Text Here}'

const res = str
  .replaceAll(/,\s*(?=[^,]*=)/g, '", "')
  .replaceAll(/\s*=\s*/g, '":"')
  .replaceAll('{', '{"')
  .replaceAll('}', '"}')

console.log(JSON.parse(res))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It is really helpful! <3

Answer (score 0):

I made you an ugly script to fix an ugly problem... ;)

```js
let string = "{Object1=Text Goes Right Here, and Here, Object2 = Another Text Here}";

let stringSplitted = string.replace(/[\{\}]/g,"").split("=")
console.log("=== Step #1")
console.log(stringSplitted)

let keys = []
let values = []
stringSplitted.forEach(function(item){
  item = item.trim()
  keys.push(item.split(" ").slice(-1).join(" "))
  values.push(item.split(" ").slice(0,-1).join(" "))
})
console.log("=== Step #2")
console.log(keys, values)

keys.pop()
values.shift()
console.log("=== Step #3")
console.log(keys, values)

let result = {}
keys.forEach(function(key, index){
  result[key] = values[index]
})
console.log("=== Result")
console.log(result)
```